# float right doesn't work

Tags: html, css

Sorry for this really basic question. I'm new in Css and try to get this to work. I have the following markup:

```
  <div class="box-title"><p>Element-Betonbecken Premium</p></div>
        <img src="img/page1/pool-top.png" class="pool-img" alt="" />
        <div class="box-small-title-right"><p>Elementtreppen</p></div>
        <div class="box-elementtreppen"></div>
```

And i have this Css for the markup:

```
.box-title {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  width: 900px !important;
  height: 67px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 67px;

}

.box-title p {
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 67px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.box-small-title-right {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  width: 460px;
  height: 40px;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 2px;
}
.box-small-title-right p  {
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 40px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.box-small-title-left {
  opacity: 0.5;
  background: #ffffff;
  width: 420px;
  height: 40px;
}


/** PAGE 1 **/

.pool-img {
  width: 420px;
  height: 220px;
  margin-top: 2px;
}

.box-elementtreppen {
  opacity: 0.5;
  background: #ffffff;
  width: 460px;
  height: 304px;
  float: right;
}
```

My Goal is to get this result:

[image]

I know there is something like positioning, but it seems, i didn't made it correctly.

Comment: Add to `.pool-img` a `float: left;` statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add float:left to this image

```
<img src="img/page1/pool-top.png" class="pool-img" alt="" />

.pool-img {
      float:left;
 }
```

so it leaves the space for the next div

Hope help

Comment: Welcome :) Accepts as Answer

Answer (score 1):

You have to give the

```
.pool-img {
  float: left;
}
```